# excel formula to entries that match a certain cell

Tags: countif, formulas, sumifs

example gift card

```
Store       Card    Amount 
Kroger      4242    100
```

On a different sheet entries

```
Store     Card      Amount
kroger    4242      50
kroger    4242      30
kroger    4242      20
```

Is there a formula that can subtract from the original amount of 100, as I continue to add entries?

So the gift card now has 20 dollars, until I use that 20 and add a new entry, then it would become 0.

Comment: Where is the column which contains the amount being subtracted?  I would expect _two_ columns, one for the amount added/subtracted, and the other for the running total.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mixing the amounts spent and the amount remaining on the different sheet, it might be ore convenient to show the remaining balance on the gift card sheet, say with:

```
=C2-SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,4242,Sheet2!C:C)
```

[image: SO37981266 example]

Assuming the card number is unique this would facilitate keeping track of a variety of cards at a variety of stores without the need for sorting.